# VB.NET - Custom Serialization and Circular References, is there a clean solution?

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization, infinite-loop, circular-reference

I'm implementing some custom serialization (to byte array), and have run into a problem handling circular references.

Example:

```
Class A
  public MyBs as new List(of B)
End class

Class B
  public MyParent as A
  public MiscInt1 as integer
  public MiscInt2 as integer
End Class
```

When serializing A, I must serialize each instance of B.

However, I have a problem when serializing B.

How do I record the parent of B without causing an infinite loop?

An idea:

If I know that an instance of B will only ever be serialized through the serialization of an instance of A, then I can handle the setup of the MyParent reference from the instance of A and not even record that information inside the byte buffer for the instance of B

This doesn't feel quite right, but it might be the best solution.

Is there a cleaner way of handling this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use approach similar to standard BinaryFormatter from BCL: utilize [ObjectIDGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.objectidgenerator.aspx) and store reference id instead of object in case of circular references

Comment: How do you know the type of the reference that you're restoring during deserialization? Are you just inferring it based upon context?

Comment: Builtin implemetation stores object identifier (plus type related information at first occurance of object instance): (A-1)(ListB-2)(B-3)(ref-1)(10)(20)(B-4)(ref-1)(100)(200). When identifier is met for the first time you store id and deserialized object. On latter appearances of this identifier you will take existing object.